# Timing skew with clock_gettime and struct stat.mtim

Tags: c, filesystems, posix, clock, real-time-clock

The following C program first gets the time using clock_gettime(), and then creates a file and reads out its modification time.  On my system at least, the file mtime is an older timestamp than the result of clock_gettime().  My question is how this can be explained, and is there a standard (such as POSIX), that would specify that both must be in order?

```
/* Compile as C11 */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec buf_start; 

    int r= clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &buf_start);
    if (r != 0) {
        perror("clock_gettime"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    FILE *file= fopen("A", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("A");
        exit(1); 
    }
    r= fputs("aaa\n", file); 
    if (r == EOF) {
        perror("A"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    r= fclose(file); 
    if (r != 0) {
        perror("A"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    struct stat stat_file;

    r= stat("A", &stat_file);
    if (r != 0) {
        perror("A"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    r= printf("%ld.%9ld\n%ld.%9ld\n",
          buf_start.tv_sec, buf_start.tv_nsec,
          stat_file.st_mtim.tv_sec, stat_file.st_mtim.tv_nsec);
    if (r < 0) {
        perror("printf"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

On my system (Ubuntu 14.04), with gcc 4.8.4 and an ext4 filesystem, the output is:

```
1463778756.834469527
1463778756.832709123
```

I.e., the startup time of the program is reported as 2 ms *after* the file's modification time.

EDIT:  With CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, the two resulting timestamps are exactly equal, down to the nanosecond.

EDIT:  The resolution as returned by clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...) is one nanosecond.

EDIT:  Added filesystem information.

Comment: What kind of results do you get with CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE ?

Comment: I get 1463786166.436852447 and 1463786166.436852447, i.e., the same number

Comment: I wonder whether the filesystem gets its timestamp from the same mechanism that is used by CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE

Comment: I believe  so, see e.g. https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/9/9/161

Comment: Thanks for the link; that explains everything precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the research by user Nos and the provided link, here is an answer to the question:  (Disclaimer:  I'm the original question asker)

On Linux, timestamps in ext4 are saved with nanosecond precision, but the timestamp itself is cached.  In regular intervals, the Linux kernel determines the nanosecond-precision time (which is an expensive operation) and saves it in a global variable.  Until the next update of that variable, all timestamps written to disk (or to some other data structures) are set to this value, and not to the current time.  As a result, the timestamp of files in an ext4 filesystem are slightly too old.  That error is on the order of a few milliseconds.

On the other hand, calling clock_gettime() to get the current time returns the (expensive to compute) high-precision current time.

As far as standards like POSIX go, I couldn't find any statement about programs like the one given in the question. I would assume such questions would be considered part of any "realtime" behaviour and not part of the usual operating system interface.

Practically, one can use CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE to get "filesystem compatible" timestamps.  This is however Linux-specific, and the fact that it works is also based on knowledge about the internal working of ext4, and may change without announcement in the future.

For the POSIX standard, I wish there was a flag CLOCK_FILESYSTEM or similar that would guarantee that programs like the one given in the question work as expected.  This would also allow clock_getres(CLOCK_FILESYSTEM) to return the actual granularity of that clock.